# compile error in do block with Maybe expected

Tags: haskell, io, option-type

Here is my code:

```
getMove :: Board -> Player -> IO (Maybe (Move, Board, Player))

completeUserTurn :: Player -> Board -> Maybe (IO (Board, Player))
completeUserTurn player board = do
    m <- getMove board player --error is here
    if isNothing m then
        Nothing
    else do
        let (move, updatedBoard, updatedPlayer) = fromJust m
        if isMoveValid board move then do
            continue <- prompt $ displayToUserForPlayer updatedBoard updatedPlayer ++ "\n" ++ "Is this correct? (y/n): "
            if continue == "y" then
                return (updatedBoard, updatedPlayer)
            else
                completeUserTurn player board
        else do
            putStr "Invalid Move!\n"
            completeUserTurn player board
```

Here is the error I am getting (On the indicated line):

```
Couldn't match expected type `Maybe t0'
                with actual type `IO (Maybe (Move, Board, Player))'
    In the return type of a call of `getMove'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: m <- getMove board player
    In the expression:
      do { m <- getMove board player;
           if isNothing m then
               Nothing
           else
               do { let ...;
                    .... } }
```

What is wrong? I though the `<-` would do the IO action and put the result in m? Why does it expect a `Maybe` then?

Comment: Because once yoiu're in the IO monad there's no escape! Have you tried changing the type signature to the one it suggests?

Comment: The type you've given is the type of a pure function that might give you an IO to perform, whereas as soon as you used getMove in a do block you made this of type IO (something). You'll need to change Nothing to return Nothing too.

Comment: You'll also need to change `return (updatedBoard, updatedPlayer)` to `return (Just (updatedBoard, updatedPlayer))` to match.

Comment: Your type signature for `completeUserTurn` doesn't make sense. If anything it should return `IO ( Maybe(...) )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### General advice

Once you've run an `IO` operation like `getMove` your function has to have type `IO ????`. Anything that does interaction with the outside world lives in the IO monad, so your function has to have type

```
completeUserTurn :: Player -> Board -> IO (Maybe (Board, Player))
```

not

```
completeUserTurn :: Player -> Board -> Maybe (IO (Board, Player))
```

The only way to have type `Maybe (IO ???)` is to not actually do any IO:

```
continue :: Bool -> Maybe (IO String)
continue False = Nothing
continue True = Just (putStrLn "Hooray! Please enter a string: " >> getLine)
```

this function doesn't actually do the `getLine` and isn't very useful, as you can check by doing

```
if isNothing (continue True) then putStrLn "nope" else putStrLn "yes"
```

in ghci: it never says Hooray. More useful would be

```
continue :: Bool -> IO (Maybe String)
continue False = return Nothing
continue True = do
   putStrLn "Hooray! Please enter a string:\n"
   xs <- getLine
   return (Just xs)
```

(Try `continue True` and `continue False` in ghci)

This one actually does the IO, so it has to have type `IO ???`.

### Your code

Anyway, your function is better expressed as

```
completeUserTurn :: Player -> Board -> IO (Maybe (Board, Player)) -- new type
completeUserTurn player board = do
    m <- getMove board player 
    if isNothing m then
        return Nothing  -- edit #1
    else do
        let (move, updatedBoard, updatedPlayer) = fromJust m
        if isMoveValid board move then do
            continue <- prompt $ displayToUserForPlayer updatedBoard updatedPlayer ++ "\n" ++ "Is this correct? (y/n): "
            if continue == "y" then
                return $ Just (updatedBoard, updatedPlayer)  -- edit #2
            else
                completeUserTurn player board
        else do
            putStr "Invalid Move!\n"
            completeUserTurn player board
```

Both **edit #1** and **edit #2** are because of the unavoidable change of type to `IO (Maybe ??)`.

Answer (score 0):

`IO (Maybe a)` is of course a very common type, but it's cumbersome to work with it directly. However, it is equivalent to `MaybeT IO a`, using the [`MaybeT` monad transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#v%3aMaybeT). With that, your code becomes just

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

getMove' :: Board -> Player -> MaybeT IO (Move, Board, Player)
getMove' board = MaybeT . getMove board    -- with your original `getMove`

completeUserTurn :: Player -> Board -> MaybeT IO (Board, Player)
completeUserTurn player board = do
    (move, updatedBoard, updatedPlayer) <- getMove' board player
    if isMoveValid board move then do
        continue <- lift . prompt
             $ displayToUserForPlayer updatedBoard updatedPlayer ++ "\n"
                    ++ "Is this correct? (y/n): "
        if continue == "y" then
            return (updatedBoard, updatedPlayer)
        else
            completeUserTurn player board
    else do
        putStr "Invalid Move!\n"
        completeUserTurn player board
```

as you see, this gets us rid of all the nasty explicit `Nothing` checking.